# jQuery $(this) pseudo selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I have a link which I want to addClass on mouseover like following:

```
$("#navbarlarge").on("mouseover","a",function(){
                $(this).addClass("linkeffect");
})
```

The issue is that I also want to add a class to both ::before and ::after pseudo elements inside the link , tried this but doesn't work:

```
$(this).find("::before").addClass("beforeeffect");
```

how can i combine this selector with the pseudo element ?

Comment: You will need pure JavaScript to do this.

Comment: Even "pure" Javascript will not allow you to match or manipulate pseudo-elements.

Comment: why not add class to parent and css `.beforeeffect:before`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - It is possible indeed!

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Show or it didn't happen ;)

Comment: Why are you trying to use `before` and `after` in JQ? just add class and define `before` and `after` in css!

Comment: @giorgio - Sure will do.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Pseudo-elements are not selectable by JavaScript and therefore are not selectable by jQuery either.

Attach the class to the element itself, and apply CSS with `#navbarlarge a`... waitaminute.

Dispense with jQuery entirely.

```css
#navbarlarge a:hover {
    /* styles to apply to hovered link */
}
#navbarlarge a:hover::before {
    /* styles to apply to hovered link before pseudo */
}
#navbarlarge a:hover::after {
    /* styles to apply to hovered link after pseudo */
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but actually that is the problem , i removed css events because i want my events to be controllable via jQuery because i trigger it elsewhere.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py why dont you show your answer please ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek Why don't you check the answers of the duplicate question?

Comment: @ProllyGeek - I will vote to repoen, if it is reopened I'll answer otherwise add a Fiddle.

Comment: @Vohuman cause simply it doesnt answer my question already checked , please reopen my question , if no one answers i will delete it no worries.

Comment: @ProllyGeek In that case, just replace `:hover` with `.someClass`

Comment: @ProllyGeek I believe some of those answers "do" answer your question, however, I'll re-open, no worries!

Comment: @Vohuman thx alot , trust me if they do i would not really ask a question here , wasting my time is not something i would do :)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py it is your chance to show long awaited answer , please do .

Comment: @Vohuman ok after reading precisely , i think some answers may afford work around however , this will make me change lot of coding in my case , so just lets wait for chip answer , if not , guess i will have to accept work arounds , thank you.

Comment: @Vohuman you can mark as duplicate , or should i delete the question

Comment: @ProllyGeek I can only "vote to close" once. I did and retracted my vote and now I can't.

Comment: @Vohuman i voted to close anyway , just want this to stay as a reference to the duplicate question just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this will help, it does the same sort of thing and you can style the span as req'd. Been trying a while and the only other way I found that was any cop was adding a style direct to the head like in this thread [SO Manipulating psuedo elems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-using-jquery), I see from the comments there was a thread posted on this thread but it isn't showing up anymore so not sure if it's the same one.

```js
$( "a" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).append( $( "<span>>>></span>" ) );
    $( this ).prepend( $( "<span><<<</span>" ) );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
    $( this ).find( "span:first" ).remove();
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Hover Me</a>
<a href="#">Hover Me</a>
```